# How I can auto-complete IP Addresses in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

What is the simple way to auto-complete IP addresses in emacs?   I used auto-complete but default configuration is not sufficient. It has difficulty expanding things with '.'. There should be a customization for this, but I failed to see it with C-h v ac..

Answer (score 3):

`hippie-expand` is generally pretty good at this sort of thing, and if the default behavior is not what you need, then you can easily add your own expansion functions to `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand has a lot of good info to help you customize it to your liking.

Comment: How I can write one for IP address?